# Azkaban Property evaluation

Tags: azkaban

We have an Azkaban property in our project that looks something like this `date" : "$(new("org.joda.time.DateTime").parse(...).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))` which is used as an argument to a spark job. The command (in the flow log) has the expression already evaluated but the generated Azkaban file (because this is defined in gradle) still contains the code string.

I couldn't find anything about how this works. Googling didn't help. There is no mention of this functionality in the docs (about `$(...)` params).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [PropsUtils.java](https://github.com/azkaban/azkaban/blob/master/az-core/src/main/java/azkaban/utils/PropsUtils.java) file you can see the method `resolveVariableExpression(final String value, final int last, final JexlEngine jexl)` actualy evaluates the prop using the `JexlEngine`.

I think this fucntionality should be added to the docs.